# Are interface methods always virtual?

Tags: class, delphi, interface, virtual

When compiling the following code I get an error:

```
TOmniParallelSimplePooledLoop = class(TOmniParallelSimpleLoop)
  procedure Execute(loopBody: TOmniIteratorSimpleSimpleDelegate); overload; override;
```

> [dcc64 Error] OtlParallel.pas(846): E2170 Cannot override a non-virtual method

If I make the ancestor method virtual then the error goes away.

However the ancestor method is declared in:

```
IOmniParallelSimpleLoop
  ...
  procedure Execute(loopBody: TOmniIteratorSimpleSimpleDelegate); overload;
```

Will the redeclaration of the base method in `TOmniParallelSimpleLoop` from non-virtual to virtual change the base type, or was the method already virtual to begin with (due to it being an implementation of an interface method)?

In other words: will the compiler output different code when an interfaced method is changed from non-virtual to virtual?

**Basic MSVC to recreate the error**

```
program Project70;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  I1 = interface
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  T1 = class(TInterfacedObject, I1)
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  T2 = class(T1)
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

procedure T1.DoSomething;
begin
  WriteLn('parent');
end;

procedure T2.DoSomething;
begin
  Writeln('Child');
end;

begin
end.
```

Comment: The real question you should be asking is how is Delphi compiling T1.  If T1.DoSomething is static.  All the COM books state that COM = VMT.  So how does T1.DoSomething get in the VMT?  I think this is where your confusion happens.  Because it's not the classes VMT for virtual Method Calls, but VMT that maps the Methods whether their Static, Virtual, or Dynamic so the interface know what method to call...here's a great artical that shows you how to implement Interface without an object. https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/04/01/interfaces-without-objects/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are interface methods always virtual?

Methods of interfaces are neither virtual nor non-virtual. That concept does not apply to methods of interfaces.

On the other hand, methods of classes can be virtual or non-virtual. The distinction determines how the method calls are bound. Virtual methods are bound at runtime, taking account of the runtime type of the object. And non-virtual methods are bound at compile time, using the compile time type of the object reference.

The compiler error is simply telling you that `override` is only meaningful for virtual methods. Your code is attempting to use `override` on a method that is not virtual. Consider this program, which does not contain any interfaces at all:

```
type
  T1 = class
    procedure DoSomething;
  end;

  T2 = class(T1)
    procedure DoSomething; override;
  end;

procedure T1.DoSomething;
begin
end;

procedure T2.DoSomething;
begin
end;

begin
end.
```

This program fails to compile with exactly the same error as your program. The error is unrelated to interfaces. Declaring `DoSomething` to be virtual when it is introduced in `T1` will resolve the error.

> Will the redeclaration of the base method in `TOmniParallelSimpleLoop` from non-virtual to virtual change the base type?

Yes it will. It changes that method from non-virtual to virtual. That means that method dispatch is performed differently, as described above. It means that the type's VMT changes to accommodate the new virtual method.

> Or was the method already virtual to begin with (due to it being an implementation of an interface method)?

The fact that a method is used to implement part of an interface does not change how the compiler treats it. A non-virtual method is implemented in the same way whether it implements an interface method or not. Likewise for a virtual method. The VMT generated to implement the interface is a distinct concern.

Elaborating on that, every method has an address. When calling a non-virtual method, the compiler knows precisely which method to call. So it can emit code to call that known method directly. For a virtual method, the compiler does not know which method will be called. That is determined by the runtime type. So the compiler emits code to read the known entry in the object's VMT, and then call that method.

Now, as I'm sure you know, interfaces are also implemented using VMTs. But that does not mean that the implementing methods get automatically promoted to being virtual. An interface is simply a VMT. The methods referred to by the interface VMT can be virtual or non-virtual, when thought of as methods of the class.

```
type
  ISomeInterface = interface
    procedure Foo;
  end;

  TSomeObject = class(TInterfacedObject, ISomeInterface)
    procedure Foo;
  end;

....

var
  Intf: ISomeInterface;
  Obj: TSomeObject;
....
Intf := TSomeObject.Create;
Obj := Intf as TSomeObject;

// non-virtual method, direct dispatch at compile time
Obj.SomeMethod; 

// interface method, dispatched via interface VMT
Intf.SomeMethod;
```

So, the fact that a method can be invoked via a VMT does not imply that it must be invoked that way.

Comment: Hm, you haven't answered the question: `Will the redeclaration of the base method [...] from basic to virtual change the base object`. I.e. will adding the `virtual` keyword cause the compiler to generate different code for TBaseObject.

Comment: "Yes it will." Are you sure? I kind of think it will not. (but not 100% sure).

Comment: 100% sure it will. You can check the emitted code. Method dispatch is completely different. The VMT is different.

Comment: So that means I can just redeclare the method and be done with it.

Comment: Well, I don't know what problem you are trying to solve. If you mean, re-declare a non virtual method, and have it implement the interface, you also need to re-declare the interface in the derived type. Remember that I don't know your underlying problem

Comment: So the declaration of the class must be like this: `TOmniParallelSimplePooledLoop = class(TOmniParallelSimpleLoop, IOmniParallelSimpleLoop, IPooledLoop)`, not like this: `TOmniParallelSimplePooledLoop = class(TOmniParallelSimpleLoop, IPooledLoop)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with these interfaces so I don't know which one you are trying to implement. But it's something along those lines.

Comment: This is all described in detail in Chapter3 of Danny Thorpe's seminal Delphi Component Design, published 1997, chapter 3, "Virtual methods and Polymorphism", esp the section "Abstract Interfaces Crossing Language Boundaries".

Comment: @Johan in your example if you change   T1 = class(TInterfacedObject, I1)
    procedure DoSomething; virtual;
  end;  Will definately cause the compiler to generate different code.  This is the basis for polymorphism.  Here's what Danny has to say: Both virtual and dynamic always introduce a new method name into a class's name space.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to this is contained in a single sentence of Danny Thorpe's "Delphi Component Design", ISBN 0-201-46136-6, I mentioned in a comment to @DavidH's answer:

"A VMT is precisely an array of function pointers", in the section "Importing Objects from DLLs - The Hard Way", p.89.

The following section, "Importing Objects from DLLs - The Smart Way" explains how an array of function pointers to members of an abstract interface can be used to call into a DLL which implements the interface and how this (stroke of genius, not just imo) provided the basis of Delphi's COM support (once it got past support via variants of D2).

Comment: Love Danny's book.

Comment: Your describing the genius of COM rather than anything specific to Delphi

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Well, sorry, I disagree. Dale Rogerson's Inside COM describes a messy (but coherent) set of solutions to a messy set of problems.  That doesn't qualify as genius to me and in any case it was not the only show in town (c.f, Corba).  Btw, the bit I quoted from D Thorpe isn't talking about COM.

Comment: Delphi interfaces are COM interfaces. The designers of COM invented them. Delphi interfaces are an implementatio of COM interfaces. VMTs existed long before Delphi. The best book on COM is Don Box's seminal work Essential COM.

Comment: One of the frustrations of Delphi interfaces is that they are so tied to COM. It would be nice sometimes not to have to implement `IUnknown`. For sure you can make your own VMT. You can create a record of method pointers. I'd like language support for non-COM interfaces.

Comment: FWIW, I cannot see anything here that answers the question. The question was whether or not a method being used as part of an interface implementation automatically promoted that method to be virtual, and therefore included in the type's VMT.